# Differentiability at (0,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Wolframalpha says that the following function is not differential over R2 but my math teacher says it is, could it be that the Wolframalpha expression is not correct? Or in fact there is someone wrong at his statement?

f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
x^2\frac{2x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2},  & \text{if $(x,y)$ != (0,0)} \\
0, & \text{if $(x,y)$ = (0,0)}
\end{cases}

Wolframalpha definition: is piecewise [{{x^2*((2x^2+y^2)/(x^2+y^2)),x!=0,y!=0},{0,x=0,y=0}}] differentiable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That function is differentiable at $(0,0)$, and $f'(0,0)$ is the null function, since\begin{align}0&\leqslant\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\&=\frac{x^2(2x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\\&\leqslant\frac{2x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\&=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\&\leqslant2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.\end{align}and $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0$.